# Meaning of "S. P. D." in letters

Tags: abbreviations, cicero, epistula

I have been reading Cicero's letters in translation on the Perseus.uchicago.edu site, but check the Latin to improve my limited ability. Most of the letters include **S. P. D.** in the salutation, and I am wondering — is this formulaic and what does it mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*SPD* is likely an acronym for *Salutem Plurimam Dicit*. When used in the phrase

> [Person X] salutem plurimam dicit [Person Y]

it literally becomes

> Person X sends many greetings to Person Y

Person X would be the sender/writer of the letter, and Person Y would be the recipient.

<sup>For more on Latin letter-writing, see [this page](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~mclennan/OM/CSC.html).</sup>

Comment: Or, similarly, "Salutes Plurimas Dico", I send many greetings (also I'm pretty sure those endings have to be plural, unless that's an idiomatic thing)

Answer (score 19):

I'll just expand slightly on @HDE226868's excellent and correct answer and say that the literal translation of *salutem plurimam dicit* is "says very much health."

Another version you're likely to see is SQPD, which stands for *salutem quam plurimam dicit*, or "says as much health as possible."

Another set of abbreviations that crops up often is SVBEEV or variants thereof. This stands for *Si vales, bene est; ego valeo* or "If you are well, that is good; I am well." It's sort of the Latin equivalent of "How are you? I am fine."

Letters often close with just *vale*, which means "be well," but sometimes you'll see *cura ut valeas*, which means "take care to be well" or "see that you are well."

Answer (score 4):

SPD can also represent Salutem Plurimam Dat which has the same meaning as those mentioned above.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you see that anywhere being used?
I ask because 'salus' is feminine and 'plurimum' isn't but both have to be the same genus.

Comment: Sorry @Cyb3rKo yes you are right it should be plurimam. I will correct it.