# How to parse "Dis Manibus" syntactically?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, syntax, inscription

Almost everyone who has ever seen a Roman grave inscription has seen the phrase *Dis Manibus* or its abbreviation *DM*.
It starts almost every Roman tombstone I have seen.
I know it means "to/for the [Manes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manes)", but I am not sure how to parse it syntactically as a part of the inscription.

Should I parse *D[is] M[anibus]* as a separate idiom that is not syntactically tied to the rest of the text?
What exactly is given or dedicated to the Manes?
Is it the tomb, the deceased, or something else?
Is the text perhaps addressed to the Manes?

I would be grateful if someone could show an example or two and explain **how the phrase *Dis Manibus* works as a part of the whole text in an epitaph**.

Here are some example inscriptions from [this CIL page](http://arachne.uni-koeln.de/Tei-Viewer/cgi-bin/teiviewer.php?manifest=BOOK-ZID883691) ("Section: Sepulchrales"):

> 15128
>   DIS MANIBVS
>   TI CLAVDIO ISSO
>   FIL DVLCISSIMO
>   VIX ANN XII D XXXV
>   IVLIA SEVERA
>   MATER FECIT
>
> 15130
>   DIS MANIBVS
>   TI CLAVDIVS
>   IVCVNDVS AVG
>   L FEC FAVSTO
>   ALVMNO SVO
>
> 15134
>   D M
>   BENE MERENTI FILIO
>   CLAVDIO LICINIO
>   QVI VIXIT ANNO
>   VNO MESIBUS VIIII
>   FECIT PATER LICINIVS
>   EVTHYCIVS

I can understand these inscriptions otherwise, but I don't see the exact role played by the first lines.
This may or may not be a representative sample.
I lack the expertise to judge that, but the ubiquity of the phrase is evident from what I have seen.

Comment: A less exact translation using current practice might be "Rest In Peace" Often abbreviated to "RIP"

Answer (score 6):

In each example you give, there is the word *fecit* or its abbreviation *fec*. I believe this goes along with *Dis Manibus* to mean "made to the Manes". In this way, it [resembles the style of Roman letters](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5369/how-do-i-address-an-email-in-latin-to-my-latin-professor/5373#5373), in which the recipient is placed up top in the dative case, and "salutem" or "S.D." often follows. Since epitaphs are short, it makes sense to place *fecit* near the end, using SOV order.

To demonstrate this theory, let's try translating each one. I wasn't able to translate each one fully, but I think I got the gist. The translations serve to illustrate how *fecit* goes hand in hand with *DM*.

Also, please feel free to improve my translations in the comments.

> **15128**
>   DIS MANIBVS
>   TI CLAVDIO ISSO
>   FIL DVLCISSIMO
>   VIX ANN XII D XXXV
>   IVLIA SEVERA
>   MATER FECIT
>
> To the spirits of the dead,
>   For Tiberius Claudius (of Issus? Issus?),
>   most sweet son,
>   lived ——
>   Iulia Severa,
>   his mother, made.
>
> **15130**
>   DIS MANIBVS
>   TI CLAVDIVS
>   IVCVNDVS AVG
>   L FEC FAVSTO
>   ALVMNO SVO
>
> To the ghost-gods,
>   Tiberius Claudius, agreeable,
>   made for his favorable foster son,
>   Lucius Augustus.
>
> N.B. I am really unsure of this translation.
>
> **15134**
>   D M
>   BENE MERENTI FILIO
>   CLAVDIO LICINIO
>   QVI VIXIT ANNO
>   VNO MESIBUS VIIII
>   FECIT PATER LICINIVS
>   EVTHYCIVS
>
> To the Manes,
>   For the well-deserving son
>   Claudius Licinius
>   who lived for one year nine months,
>   his father Licinius Euthycius made.

Comment: Thanks! To clarify: Are you saying that the text on the tombstone is addressed to the Manes? It looks reasonable to me, but it is worth noting that the name of the deceased is also in dative.

Comment: I think the double dative might be understood as a *dativus finalis* and a *dativus commodi*. I'm inclined to say that "Dis Manibus" would be the *dativus commodi*.

Comment: Hmm... So it would be something like "This person made for that person for the benefit of the Manes"? The L is probably the name Lucius, and I think it's the name of the *alumnus* (probably foster son rather than student).

Comment: Ah, thanks! I corrected that translation. Feel free to point out any other problems, with that one or others. Regarding your question, that's how I understand it.

Comment: Sandys, Latin epigraphy, takes the dative DM to be in apposition to the dative name of the deceased. Another, more general-interest book that I looked in, Keppie's Understanding Latin inscriptions, says we're meant to understand 'et' between the 2 datives. Cooley, The Cambridge manual of Latin epigraphy, always treats DM as a separate, standalone invocation. There's also the fact that sometimes DM = DMS (dis manibus sacrum), where the dative is dependent on the adj. Plus, sometimes the person's name isn't dative at all, though DM still is. The matter is, in short, very complicated.

Comment: I should also add that the 3 examples given here aren't necessarily very representative. Not all have the verb fecit and, as I indicate in my previous comment, the person's name isn't always in the dative. In some, it's in the genitive and depends on DM ('to the spirits of the departed of so-and-so'), in others it's nominative, and I'm sure I've seen accusatives too. So, either the meaning/syntax of DM is highly flexible (a definite possibility) or Cooley is right always to take it as a standalone invocation (though there may well be instances where that approach doesn't work).

Comment: @cnread Can you post those comments as an answer? I had no idea the matter was so complicated and unclear. Unfortunately I lack the insight to pick representative examples from CIL.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase is often DIS MANIBUS SACRUM.  I.e. "Sacred/Dedicated to the spirits of the departed".  So the "sacrum" is understood.

Treat it as a separate sentence, indicating what the nature of the inscription is.  Abbreviated D.M. or D.M.S.  There are 19,000 plus examples in Clauss-Slaby.

E.g.  CIL 7298.

D(is) M(anibus) s(acrum) / Vera Tumiano fratri / bene merenti fecit / vixit annis XXXV / mens(ibus) VIII die(bu)s XV

Answer (score 1):

Originally it was syntactically tied to FECIT as a normal dative expressing the recipient/beneficiary, parallel to the name of the deceased - monuments were originally erected and dedicated to honour the supernatural, and in a way this commemorated the fact that the deceased had joined the ranks of the Ancestral Spirits.

In the course of time it became idiomatic as the default opener, abbreviated as D·M. This, coupled with the fact that usually there's another dative (the name of the deceased) already attached to the same FECIT, might have lead to its eventual reinterpretation as a syntactically independent formula. As a result it became possible and extremely common to use it in inscriptions that contain no verb like FECIT/POSVIT at all. That said, one always can (and probably should) understand such a verb as being implied.

Some examples of the usage without a verb are found [in this PDF](https://latininscriptions.ashmus.ox.ac.uk/resources/resources/CrackingCodesinLatinInscriptionsTeacherNotes.pdf); another would be [this burial urn](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/object/G_1856-1226-1737).

DIS·MANIBVS·SACRVM should be understood in the same way, with the verb FECIT implied, where SACRVM·FECIT is a more solemn, religious, periphrastic way to say *cōnsecrāvit* "made holy as an honour/offering, dedicated", but unlike the latter additionally meaning "made a sacred ritual". It's not like a warning-sign saying
"don't touch - sacred!", as far as I can judge.